# ttf file in @font-face is not working on a Windows laptop

Tags: css, font-face

I'm new to web dev, not sure if this is a common issue. I was trying to use font-face to implement a font in TTF format.

I tried

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Univers-light-normal";
  src: url(font-family/Univers-light-normal.ttf);
}
```

and also

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Univers-light-normal";
  src: url(font-family/Univers-light-normal.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

But neither worked. I also tried clearing my browser's cache, but it still wasn't working. Though when I opened the same HTML/CSS files on a Mac this time (was originally using Windows laptop, but using Google Chrome on both laptops), it does seem to be working.

I already installed the font. And the first code work for OTF files just fine. I am guessing the file I got is a Mac TrueType fonts instead of a Windows TrueType fonts? If so, is there a way to tell the difference? And how can I get it to work on a Windows laptop?

Please also let me know if there are other possible reasons this isn't working.

Comment: Which browser on which Windows OS?

Comment: Google Chrome on Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit version

Comment: In Chrome, if you press F12 then you will get to the developer tools. If you look in the network tab ([docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/)), you can check if the browser found the font file, and in the [console tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/) it will tell you about any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this because it worked for me:

- Single quotation marks for src
- Try to find precisely the folder that has the TTF file and, for example, './fonts/SFAtarianSystem.ttf'

Or you can check out this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Also, try to use the URL for the font (more usability) instead of local because sometimes it may cause a problem if the font is not reloaded.